# What power cord does the original playstation 3 use?

Tags: ps3, hardware

I have an original Playsation 3. My question is what hardware do i need to buy to power this Playstation 3? I have the actual ps3, and the hdmi cable, but nothing to power it.

As a sub-question, does the ps3 slim power equipment work for the original ps3?

Comment: It might help if you specify what country/region this PS3 is from.

Comment: Actually, it probably wont help. The female end of the IEC 60320 series of cables is identical regardless of region. It will however make a difference when ordering one online, possibly. However, when walking into a store in your own region, if they sold anything other than the specific region's cable, I'd slap the manager...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The original PS3 used a cable that looks similar to a PC power cord, like [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000KIPE0I):

[image: Original PS3 power cable]

The newer "slim" PS3's use a [a different plug-in](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005ZL5XRO) that looks like this:

[image: New PS3 Power Cable]

The two are not interchangeable. If you look at the back of your PS3, it will be obvious which one you need.

And yes, the correct power cable is the only piece of hardware you need to power a PS3.

Comment: I'm not sure the second one is a proprietary cable. It looks very much like a standard figure-of-8 lead.

Answer (score 2):

To further add to BlueRaja's answer. The cable type required to power PS3's is of the [IEC 60320](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60320) family, Specifically: `C7` and `C13` types, with earlier models utilising `C13`.

All of which are IEC standard female couplers. The only difference as Powerlord has stated, would be your region, which would require you to find the correct plug/adapter for your mains sockets.

And as already stated, the only way to tell which you need is to check the port at the back of your console.